# textarea duplicate string check ignoring leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: javascript, duplicates

Users will enter various serials in a `textarea`. Each newline will indicate a new serial. Some requirements/restrictions:

- Leading and trailing white spaces are not allowed.
- White space within a serial is okay.
- Blank serials are not allowed
- I'd prefer to not use JQuery.
- Store duplicates so they can be shown to the user.

Based on my tests I have a working solution. I want to make sure I'm not missing or overlooking anything. My questions are:

- Is there a more efficient ways to check for duplicates?
- Are there any glaring test cases that my solution won't catch?

**Working Example**: http://jsbin.com/ivusuj/1/

```
function duplicateCheck() {
    var output = document.getElementById('Output');
    output.innerHTML = '';
    var duplicateSerials = [];
    var count = 0;
    var textArea = document.getElementById('Serials'); 
    var serials = textArea.value.trim().split(/ *\n */);

    for(var i = 0;i < serials.length;i++){
      var serial = serials[i];

      if(serials.indexOf(serial) != serials.lastIndexOf(serial) && 
         duplicateSerials.indexOf(serial) == -1 && serial !== '') {        
        duplicateSerials.push(serial);
      }  

    }    

  // For testing
  output.innerHTML = '<pre>Serials:\t' + serials.toString() + "<br />" +
                     'Duplicates:\t' + duplicateSerials.toString() + "<br>" +
                     '</pre>';
}
```

**Note:** the above is for a client side check. The same check will be performed server side as well to ensure the data is valid.

---

**Update**

Solution comparison: http://jsbin.com/ivusuj/4/edit

Comment: I know this is nit picky, but just something you may want to think about if you are going to be sharing code. Usually for a function like this you would want to start with a lower case letter. It seems to be convention that starting a name with an upper case letter is reserved for functions that are meant to be instantiated (i.e. a function that is meant to be used as a "class").

Comment: No worries; I appreciate the advice. I actually had it that way and then changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd get significantly better performance if you used an object to determine which serials you'd seen before.  Something closer to this:

```
var seen = {};
for (var i = 0, j = serials.length; i < j; ++i) {
  var serial = serials[i];
  if (seen.hasOwnProperty(serial)) {
    // Dupe code goes here.
    continue;
  }
  // Can't be a duplicate if we get to this point.
}
```

Though that won't work with serials that use periods.

Comment: I'd still look at adapting your approach to use an Object for the lookup, even if you don't go with this exact solution (create a hash of serials and put them into the object, for example [I realize, a bit overkill]).  Your current `serials.indexOf(serial) != serials.lastIndexOf(serial)` is upper bounded very near O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

I put together a jsfiddle her: http://jsfiddle.net/wrexroad/yFJjR/3/

Actually checking for duplicates that way is pretty inefficient.

Instead of checking for duplicates, this just adds a property to an object where the property's name is is the serial. Then it prints out all of the property names.

This way if you have duplicates, it will just create the property, then overwrite it.

Here is the function:

```
function duplicateCheck() {
    var output = document.getElementById('Output');
        output.innerHTML = '';

    var textArea = document.getElementById('Serials'); 
    var inputSerials = 
        textArea.value.trim().split(/ *\n */);
    var outputSerials = new Object();

    for(var i = 0;i < inputSerials.length;i++){
        var serial = inputSerials[i];

        //build an object whose properties are serials
        //if the serial exists, incremint a counter
        if(outputSerials[serial]){
            outputSerials[serial]++;
        }else{
            outputSerials[serial] = 1;
        }
    }    

   output.innerHTML = 
      'Serials: <br />'; 

   for(var i in outputSerials){
      output.innerHTML += i + " ";
   }

   output.innerHTML += 
      '<br /><br />Duplicate Serials: <br />'; 

    for(var i in outputSerials){
    //check to see if we have any duplicates
       if(outputSerials[i] > 1){
           output.innerHTML += i + " ";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is certainly faster, but how would I keep track of the duplicate serials? I want to warn the user of duplicate serial(s) and display them. This is important from a usability stand point.

Comment: I didn't realize that was a requirement. I will modify it. Give me a minute or three...

Comment: Actually, using g.d.d.c code I was able to achieve this requirement. It follows pretty straight forward from your code.

Comment: Well, I had already updated it so I am posting anyway. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to filter out duplicates.

```
function formatInput() {
    var arrUnique = [], dups = [],
    str = document.getElementById('Serials').value
        .replace(/\r\n?/g,'\n')
        // normalize newlines - not sure what PC's
        // return. Mac's are using \n's
        .replace(/(^((?!\n)\s)+|((?!\n)\s)+$)/gm,'')
        // trim each line
        .replace(/^\n+|\n+$|\n+(?=\n(?!\n))/g,''),
        // delete empty lines and trim the whole string
    arr = str.length ? str.split(/\n/) : [];
    // split each line, if any
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arrUnique.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
            arrUnique.push(arr[i]);
        else dups.push(arr[i]);
    }
    //document.getElementById('Serials').value = arrUnique.join('\n');
    console.log('serials:', arr);
    console.log('unique:', arrUnique);
    console.log('duplicates:', dups);
}
```